# How to disable "Verify HUAWEI ID" notification?

Tags: notifications, emui, huawei-p20

How to get rid of this reminder if I do not have any HUAWEI ID, and have not ever used HUAWEI cloud?

[image: IMG:]

Device: HUAWEI P20 EML-L29 8.1.0.164
EMUI: ⠀8.1.0
Kernel: 4.4.103+

Comment: If you go to Settings - Accounts, do you have a HUAWEI or Huawei Cloud account there? If so, have you tried deleting it?

Comment: I do not have any account on this phone. However, following the instructions from the answer by Vivdo got rid of this stupid notification immediately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you pull down the notification bar and slide the notification message to the right you can access the notification settings via the cog symbol.

Alternatively this notification comes from the Huawei 'Files' app, find it in apps and notifications and kill that app!.